# Multiple AUTH_USER_MODEL In django

Tags: django, authentication

In my Django project (which is a REST API) I'm having a problem that has probably been encountered before yet I can't find a good solution to it anywhere. In my project I have 2 different kinds of users, "Mobile app users" and "Business users". The mobile app users can go into our mobile app and see content around them based on geolocation. The business users can log on to a web admin portal and generate the content that the mobile app user sees. As a caveat there is also the possibility that a business user can also be an app user.
I want to be able to allow a business user and an app user to have the same email while still having it be unique to their model.

Now Problem is how It is possible to create a two account(1st is mobile app & 2nd is business) with same Email ID..

Comment: Do you really have to create two user record for this scenario? Groups/Permissions might be a good way to address this - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/default/#permissions-and-authorization.

Comment: yes I have to create two record, beacuse user Information may be different. I want each and every thing different for both type of user. There should be no relationship.

Answer (score 5):

### Possible solutions in general:

There is a few possible solutions to deal with different type of users. According to your situation you should. This article covers the subject in many ways:
[How to Implement Multiple User Types with Django](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/18/how-to-implement-multiple-user-types-with-django.html)

### Approach discussed in the article summarized:

1. Use always only one Django model to handle authentication, even if you have different type of users. As @Anton Perepelitcyn and @Anderw pointed out, we can still have multiple user models for other purposes using relations.
2. According to your situation choose best solution for you:[image]

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you have a custom `User`. Then

```
class MobileUser:
    credentials = models.OneToOne(User, related_name='mobile_user')
    ...

class BusinessUser:
    credentials = models.OneToOne(User, related_name='business_user')
    ...
```

You may add some necessary fields to custom `User` which may allow you to better control access (like boolean `is_business` and `is_mobile`). Also use `roles` or `permissions`.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say your basic `AUTH_USER_MODEL` model is for storing "Mobile app users". 
You should add another one model that stores some additional information for "Business users" and it must be related to the `AUTH_USER_MODEL` model, that's all.

Comment: In that case How we wil create Two sperate Account(Mobile user & business) with same Email Id?

Comment: Groups and Permissions to the rescue.
Its tedious, but you can do one thing:
Create relevant permissions and groups. For example, create a permissions spec for business user to be able to access all endpoints of API and mobile app user to only be able to access mobile app related parts of the API.This way, you can use the same authentication model and control behaviour for each type of user from within each view, either by using a Mixin if multiple views should behave somewhat similar or by configuring each view to behave differently, based on the user accessing it.